# how do I tell maven to update the local metadata?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to understand how to get maven to update the local maven-metadata-local.xml file, by checking what artifact versions are available in our maven repository, and updating the `release` tag in the local metadata file to the latest version.

My team and I are working on a large codebase consisting of several code modules.  These modules have dependencies on each other.

For example, the ER_catalog module depends on ER_CORE_api, so in the ER_catalog pom.xml, we declare a dependency on ER_CORE_api, and use the version RELEASE.

Maven then looks in the local metadata to see what the latest release of ER_CORE_api is, and uses that to compile the code in ER_catalog.

My local version of this metadata file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
<groupId>com.company.er</groupId>
<artifactId>ER_CORE_api</artifactId>
<versioning>
<release>0.562.0</release>
<versions>
  <version>0.561.0</version>
  <version>0.562.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <version>0.562.0</version>
  <version>0.563.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <version>0.564.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </versions>
  <lastUpdated>20150513150410</lastUpdated>
 </versioning>
</metadata>
```

However, my colleague has recently uploaded version 0.563.0 (using the maven release plugin).  So on the repository where the artifact lives, the metadata looks like this:

```
<metadata>
<groupId>com.company.er</groupId>      
<artifactId>ER_CORE_api</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>0.563.0</latest>
<release>0.563.0</release>
<versions><version>0.561.0</version>
<version>0.562.0</version><version>0.563.0</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20150513122648</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

My code won't compile, because it is asking the local maven repo for the latest version of ER_CORE_api, and getting 0.562.0 instead of 0.563.0.   How can I trigger a refresh of this metadata (short of deleting the file) ?

NB I know somebody will say that we should be using specific version tags, not RELEASE.  Here's why we are using RELEASE:

We might have 5 modules which depend on ER_CORE_api.  If each of them have a hard-coded version for ER_CORE_api, then when we update ER_CORE_api to a new version, each of those modules must be updated - and then they must all have a new version created too (since they have changed).  This means that every change would trigger a cascade of changes up the dependency tree, which is a lot of work. Plus, there's no easy way to find out which modules depend on the module I've changed.

When we freeze a release of the application, we put specific versions in the pom.xml files for all modules.